# IF statement with multiple AND/OR conditions

Tags: c#

I have if statement with many checks. There must be a better way to implement this.
Does someone have an idea on how to improve this method?
I have many similar methods in production. I would like to do the refactoring.

```
 private void CheckWorkingHoursValidity(WorkingDayRequestDto workingDayDto)
 {
     if (!workingDayDto.MondayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.MondayStart.HasValue ||
         workingDayDto.MondayEnd.HasValue && !workingDayDto.MondayStart.HasValue ||
         !workingDayDto.TuesdayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.TuesdayStart.HasValue ||
         workingDayDto.TuesdayEnd.HasValue && !workingDayDto.TuesdayStart.HasValue ||
         !workingDayDto.WednesdayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.WednesdayStart.HasValue ||
         workingDayDto.WednesdayEnd.HasValue && !workingDayDto.WednesdayStart.HasValue ||
         !workingDayDto.ThursdayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.ThursdayStart.HasValue ||
         workingDayDto.ThursdayEnd.HasValue && !workingDayDto.ThursdayStart.HasValue ||
         !workingDayDto.FridayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.FridayStart.HasValue ||
         workingDayDto.FridayEnd.HasValue && !workingDayDto.FridayStart.HasValue ||
         !workingDayDto.SaturdayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.SaturdayStart.HasValue ||
         workingDayDto.SaturdayEnd.HasValue && !workingDayDto.SaturdayStart.HasValue ||
         !workingDayDto.SundayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.SundayStart.HasValue ||
         workingDayDto.SundayEnd.HasValue && !workingDayDto.SundayStart.HasValue)
     {
         throw new ValidationException("Both start and end time must be set or empty");
     }

     if (workingDayDto.MondayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.MondayStart.HasValue &&
         TimeSpan.Compare(workingDayDto.MondayEnd.Value, workingDayDto.MondayStart.Value) <= 0 ||
         workingDayDto.TuesdayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.TuesdayStart.HasValue &&
         TimeSpan.Compare(workingDayDto.TuesdayEnd.Value, workingDayDto.TuesdayStart.Value) <= 0 ||
         workingDayDto.WednesdayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.WednesdayStart.HasValue &&
         TimeSpan.Compare(workingDayDto.WednesdayEnd.Value, workingDayDto.WednesdayStart.Value) <= 0 ||
         workingDayDto.ThursdayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.ThursdayStart.HasValue &&
         TimeSpan.Compare(workingDayDto.ThursdayEnd.Value, workingDayDto.ThursdayStart.Value) <= 0 ||
         workingDayDto.FridayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.FridayStart.HasValue &&
         TimeSpan.Compare(workingDayDto.FridayEnd.Value, workingDayDto.FridayStart.Value) <= 0 ||
         workingDayDto.SaturdayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.SaturdayStart.HasValue &&
         TimeSpan.Compare(workingDayDto.SaturdayEnd.Value, workingDayDto.SaturdayStart.Value) <= 0 ||
         workingDayDto.SundayEnd.HasValue && workingDayDto.SundayStart.HasValue &&
         TimeSpan.Compare(workingDayDto.SundayEnd.Value, workingDayDto.SundayStart.Value) <= 0)
     {
         throw new ValidationException("End time cannot be before or same as start time");
     }
 }
```

Comment: This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `WorkingDayRequestDto workingDayDto`

The name of this object is IMO misleading because it seems to represent a whole week. I would call it `WorkWeek`.

---

If it's possible to change the data model, I would invent a `WorkDay` object with a `Start` and `End` time:

```
public class WorkDay
{
  public WorkDay(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
  {
    Start = start;
    End = end;
  }

  public DayOfWeek? DayOfWeek => Start != null ? (DayOfWeek?)Start.Value.DayOfWeek : null;
  public DateTime? Start { get; }
  public DateTime? End { get; }

  public bool IsValid
  {
    get
    {
      return Start != null && End != null  && Start <= End && Start.Value.DayOfWeek == End.Value.DayOfWeek || Start == null && End == null;
    }
  }

  // And/Or

  public void CheckIsValid()
  {
    if (Start == null && End != null || Start != null && End == null)
      throw new WorkDayNullCheckException(this);
    if (Start != null && End != null && (Start > End || Start.Value.Date != End.Value.Date)
      throw new WorkDayInvalidStateException(this);
  }

}
```

and then `WorkWeek` could be defined as something like:

```
public class WorkWeek
{
  public WorkDay Monday { get; set; }
  public WorkDay Tuesday { get; set; }
  public WorkDay Wednesday { get; set; }
  public WorkDay Thursday { get; set; }
  public WorkDay Friday { get; set; }
  public WorkDay Saturday { get; set; }
  public WorkDay Sunday { get; set; }

  public WorkDay[] Days => new WorkDay[] { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday };

  public bool IsValid => Days.All(d => d.IsValid);

  // And/Or

  public void CheckValidity()
  {
    foreach (var day in Days.Where(d => d != null))
    {
      day.CheckIsValid();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you made a list for EndForDays and StartForDays and do loop?

For example, I made a code snippet by Java.

```
List<Boolean> EndForDays = Arrays.asList(true, false, false);
List<Boolean> StartForDays = Arrays.asList(true, true, true);

for(int i = 0; i < EndForDays.size(); i++) {
    if(!EndForDays.get(i) && StartForDays.get(i)) {
        // throw
    }

    if(EndForDays.get(i) && !StartForDays.get(i)) {
        // throw
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that great at C#, however in other languages when I come across something like this, I usually write a private or helper function to iterate through the object so my code doesn't look like large blocks of checks.

Something like

```
private void checkDays(WorkingDayRequestDto  dayObject){
        string [] days = new string[]  { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday", "Sunday" };
        foreach(string x in days){
            DayType start = typeof(DayType).GetProperty( days[x] + "Start");
            DayType end = typeof(DayType).GetProperty( days[x] + "End");
            if(!end.HasValue && start.HasValue || end.HasValue && !start.HasValue){
                throw new ValidationException("Both start and end time must be set or empty");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't speak C#, but you could probably simplify the code somewhat by using the exclusive or operator ^ . `if(end.HasValue ^ start.HasValue ){
                throw new ValidationException("Both start and end time must be set or empty");`
            }